# calculation expect pension payout given survival probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, actuarial-science

Just wondering. How is the expected pension payout calculated, given an agreed fixed annual payment of a made up figure of 1000, whilst linking it to survival probabilities coming from life tables (I deliberately ignore inflation and other factors). Is it simply a question of multiplying each amount by the pensioner's survival probability depending on age as indicated in this table:

[image]

Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

PS:

This above survival probabilities come (I think) from [UK life tables](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/lifeexpectancies/datasets/nationallifetablesunitedkingdomreferencetables). These tables contain information like the following depending on age and gender:

mx
is the central rate of mortality, defined as the number of deaths at age x last birthday in the three year period to which the National Life Table
relates divided by the average population at that age over the same period.

qx
is the mortality rate between age x and (x +1), that is the probability that a person aged x exact will die before reaching age (x +1).

lx
is the number of survivors to exact age x of 100,000 live births of the same sex who are assumed to be subject throughout their lives to the
mortality rates experienced in the three year period to which the National Life Table relates.

dx
is the number dying between exact age x and (x +1) described similarly to lx, that is dx=lx-lx+1.

ex
is the average period expectation of life at exact age x, that is the average number of years that those aged x exact will live thereafter
based on the mortality rates experienced in the three year period to which the National Life Table relates.

I would think, that 1 - qx represents the survival probability but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a fixed annual payment of 1000 per year, we can treat the pension plan as a life annuity. The actuarial present value (APV) of a life annuity paying 1 per year is given by $$APV=a_x=\sum _{t=1}^\infty v^t{_tp_x}$$
where $v^t=(1+i)^{-1}$ is the discount factor and $_tp_x$ is the probability of a life aged $x$ surviving $t$ years. In your case of $i=0$ (no interest rate), we have $v^t=1$, and the above expression becomes $$APV=a_x=\sum_{t=1}^\infty{_tp_x}$$
So the expected payout of your annuity is just $$1000\sum_{t=1}^\infty {_tp_x}$$
Where $$_tp_x=\prod _{k=0}^{t-1}{p_{x+k}}$$

Comment: Thanks. So basically what I said. The reason I asked is because I have an excel here where the person compounded the survival probabilities before multiplying. I do not understand why ... so for year 1 the above formula applies. for year 2 survival prob from year one and 2 are first multiplied

Comment: I'm not too sure about what "survival probability" means in your table -- for example is 0.94 referring to the survival probability between age 71 and 72 (over the period of one year), or is it referring to that between ages 70 and 72?

Comment: if it's referring to one-year survival probabilities then the reason why we have to "compound" them is that for someone to survive age 71 with 0.94 probability, the person first has to survive age 70 with 0.95 probability

Comment: thanks. I will have to double check this and will get back to you.

Comment: I am still trying to establish the survival probability question (see adapted question's PS section).

Comment: Note that the survival probabilities in UK life tables ($p_x$) are given as one-year survival probabilities. For instance $p_{70}$ refers to the probability that given a person is alive at age 70, he would survive until age 71. That's why we need to do the "compounding"

Comment: Thanks so the compounding is necessary. Thanks. Maybe you could be so kind and adapt the answer please? I like the inclusion of the discount rate, which I need to consider as well but let us just focus on the survival side? Can I please ask, is there a nice text book/link for this? I would love to read up on this. Thanks!

Comment: You might wanna check out Actuarial Mathematical for Life Contingent Risks, 2nd edition by Dickson D.C.M, Hardy M.R. and Waters H.R., 2013. By "adapting" the answer do you mean to accept it? That can be done on your side

Comment: sorry I thought the (compounding) calculation of px needs to baked into the formula. but maybe you assume that the correct probability is plugged in?

Comment: Oh I just edited the answer

Comment: Thanks. That's what I meant. Can I please ask what the reason for discounting really is? Is it because the company making the payment simply borrows it and pays the interest i? Or does this account for inflation.

Comment: For example if a life aged 70 survives until he is 72, the $1000 pension payment when he is 72 is not worth $1000 at the time when he is 70. You need to discount it with the appropriate discount factor

Comment: yes thanks. I understand that part of the present value. I am thinking about it from the companies point of view. TBH I am not sure if they "fork out" a total at the beginning and invest it but pay the payments or if they borrow the money to make the payments. sorry this is more a chat now. thanks for all your help!

Comment: From the company's point of view, you may think of it as: to make the 1000 pension payment at $t=2$, the company would choose to invest $1000v^2$ in the risk-free asset at $t=0$. So the company does not actually have to keep 1000 in case they have to make the pension payment at $t=2$

Comment: thanks. all pretty new to me. the math is not too bad but i do not fully understand the mechanics. Thanks!